# Perl: Find duplicate in excel/csv file and write an output file with them

Tags: string, perl, excel, list

First of all I am a completely newbie (for now) with Perl, and I would like to ask you a quick advice.

I have to deal with a some lists of journals and publishers in different Excel/CSV files. I would like to find a way to cross the data in order to have the list of the titles & publishers in common between two files, and a list with the publisher and the number of journal published.

I would like to ask you if it is possible to do it with Perl (it should be the best method for what I understood, but I would like a confirmation!), and how advance it is.

Sorry for the strange request but I am writing my thesis and I would not like to spend time on something and discover that is not possible!
Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a perfect problem for Perl. If you provide some sample data with your desired output, you might even get some help with the implementation from me (or someone faster than me with Perl).

Comment: I assume you mean CSV--"comma separated values". The cvs tag is going to draw searches for the version control system called "CVS".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- To parse a CSV file:

  [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS)
- To parse an Excel file:

  [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel)
- To find the common elements of two lists:

  ```
  my %list1 = map { $_ => 1 } @list1;
  my @common = grep $list1{$_}, @list2;
  ```

Comment: maybe best choice will be [intersect function](https://metacpan.org/module/Array::Utils)?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm going to take a look at both of them an try to write something, in case I will return here to ask for help!